# Sql Inner Join with Two Conditions on Same Field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`table_a`:

```
id        label
-----------------
1         l1
2         l2
3         l3
```

`table_b`:

```
table_a_id      table_c_id
---------------------------
1               1
1               3
1               4
2               2
2               4
3               1
3               4
3               8
```

How can I select all records from `table_a` that are associated with both table_c_id 1 AND 4? Is it possible to have n table_c_id conditions?

The following is wrong, but it illustrates what is needed.

```
SELECT table_a.* 
 FROM table_a
 JOIN table_b ON ( table_a_id = id 
               AND table_c_id = 1
               AND table_c_id = 4 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IN clause.

**EDIT:** Updated the query based on the comments posted.

```
SELECT a.* 
      FROM table_a a INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT table_a_id
               FROM table_b
            WHERE table_c_id IN(1,4)
                GROUP BY  table_a_id 
               HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table_c_id) > 1
                --HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 --This scenario will not address repeating table_c_id's
        ) b 
ON a.id = b.table_a_id
```

Comment: I need an `AND` clause because there must be two links. The results of the example would be records ID=1 and ID=3 because they both have mapping (1>1, 1>4, 3>1, 3>4) ID=2 doesn't appear because it only has (2>4)...it is missing (2>1)

Comment: @Lea: Updated the post.Pls chk

Comment: If there are two records in table_b with table_c_id = 1, it will incorrectly return this result

Comment: If there's nothing to ensure `table_c_id` is uniquely paired with `table_a_id`, the `COUNT` will include false positives (IE: duplicates of "4").  But I didn't downvote you

Comment: @OMG Poines: Agreed. In that case your answer is better. Will update the query to consider distinct c_id's

Comment: @Cybernate that seems to work great. I found that `SELECT table_a.* FROM table_a JOIN table_b as b1 ON (b1.table_a_id = id and b1.table_b_id = 1)  JOIN table_b as b2 ON (b2.table_a_id = id and b2.table_b_id = 4)` also works, does yours perform better?

Comment: @Lea Hayes: It depends on the how big the tables are and how the indexes are defined. Check the query plan using EXPLAIN

Comment: @cybernate tables could become very large, I will also need to perform queries like (1 AND 4) OR (7 AND 28) OR (1 AND 4 AND 9). I will look into EXPLAIN.

Comment: @cybernate, @OMG Ponies thanks again for the help. Using a mix of the different approaches I was able to get queries with complex mixes of ANDs and ORs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM table_a a
  JOIN (SELECT t.table_a_id
          FROM table_b t
         WHERE t.table_c_id IN (1, 4) 
      GROUP BY t.table_a_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.table_c_id) = 2) b ON b.table_a_id = a.id
```

To get matching table_a rows which are associated to table_c's 1 & 4 as a pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* , b.table_c_id
FROM table_b b
LEFT JOIN table_a a ON table_a_id = a.id
WHERE b.table_c_id =1
OR b.table_c_id =4
```